# Почему в консоль выводится Solution$Cat@74a14482?

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat2 = new Cat("Barsik", 3, 3, 3);
        System.out.println(cat2);
    }
    public static class Cat{

        public static int count = 0;
        private String name;
        private int age;
        private int weight;
        private int strength;

        public Cat(String name, int age, int weight, int strength) {
            count++;
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.strength = strength;
//            public String toString() { return name; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, Вам закомментированный toString надо раскомментировать и вынести из конструктора (как оно туда попало вообще??)

Comment: А то, что выводится сейчас - это результат работы toString из класса Object, который реализуется как getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Операторы вывода, например `println`  неявно вызывают метод `toString` у объекта (он присутствует у всех объектов). Этот метод служит для представления объекта в виде строки.

У каждого класса реализация метода своя. К примеру у `Integer` такой код:

```html
public static String toString(int i, int radix) {
        if (radix < Character.MIN_RADIX || radix > Character.MAX_RADIX)
            radix = 10;

        /* Use the faster version */
        if (radix == 10) {
            return toString(i);
        }

        char buf[] = new char[33];
        boolean negative = (i < 0);
        int charPos = 32;

        if (!negative) {
            i = -i;
        }

        while (i <= -radix) {
            buf[charPos--] = digits[-(i % radix)];
            i = i / radix;
        }
        buf[charPos] = digits[-i];

        if (negative) {
            buf[--charPos] = '-';
        }

        return new String(buf, charPos, (33 - charPos));
}
```

Как видим метод возвращает строку (грубо говоря) `return new String(buf, charPos, (33 - charPos));`

У других классов всё тоже самое. Его можно реализовать в любом классе. Можно написать там все что угодно, хоть `return "hello, world";` А этот самый `System.out.println` неявно вызовет этот самый метод `toString` у объекта и выведет этот самый "hello, world".

По умолчанию для объекта, если не переопределить метод `toString()`, приведет нас в метод `java.lang.Object.toString` (т.к. `Cat` это объект и  неявно так сказать наследник класса `java.lang.Object`), а у класса `Object` по умолчанию в методе `ToString()` написана строка:

`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

которую вы как раз и видите.

[пруф](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())  :-)

Как следствие, чтобы видеть что-то человеческое при выводе объекта с помощью операторов вывода - нужно определить некую логику в методе `toString()`

В вашем случае нужно просто этот метод раскомментировать и вынести из конструктора (потому, что как оказался у вас метод внутри конструктора мне непонятно).

```
public static class Cat {

    ...
    // объявление полей
    ...

    public Cat(String name, int age, int weight, int strength) {
        ...
        // некая логика конструктора
        ...
    }

    // волшебный метод, который превращает объект не в непонятные символы,
    // а в нечто человекочетаемое и симпатичное глазу
    public String toString() { 
        return name; 
    } 
}
```

При записи

```
Cat cat2 = new Cat("Barsik", 3, 3, 3);
System.out.println(cat2);
```

он будет выводить `Barsik`

Comment: Благодарю вас за развернутый и (на мой взгляд) блестящий ответ. А как сделать, что бы выводил не только Barsik, но и остальные параметры? И нельзя ли без этого достойного метода обойтись? Я, может быть неправильно, думаю ,что метод toString() экстремальный что-ли...

Comment: @Шаукат вы в этом методе можете написать всё, что вашей душе угодно. Можете написать `return "Имя: " + name + ",\n Возраст: " + age + ",\n Вес: " + weight;` Если утрированно, то это было бы тоже самое, что создать лишний метод `showInfo()` в котором было бы написано:
`System.out.println("Имя: " + name);System.out.println("Возраст: " + age);System.out.println("Вес: " + weight);` ........нормальный метод. Не зря ж он есть для всех всех всех объектов в Java)

Comment: Теперь, я нашел в вашем ответе то что искал. Еще раз благодарю вас. Жизнь повеселела).

Comment: @Шаукат странно, мой ответ именно то, что нужно, но отметили верным другой)) юмор оценил))

Comment: Извиняюсь, промахнулся.)

Answer (score 0):

Раскомментируйте строку  public String toString()
Ваш код:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat2 = new Cat("Barsik", 3, 3, 3);
        System.out.println(cat2);
    }

    public static class Cat {

        public static int count = 0;
        private String name;
        private int age;
        private int weight;
        private int strength;

        public Cat(String name, int age, int weight, int strength) {
            count++;
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.strength = strength;
        }

        public String toString() {          return name;        }
    }
}
```